# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to pull data from an XML credit report.  I need the ability to weed out certain entries.

This is the code I am using to try to get the list of values.

```
            var trades = from x in xmlStr.Descendants("USTrade")
                    where (int) x.Element("BalanceAmount") > 0
                      select  (int)x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount");
```

Sample Data looks as follows:

```
      <USTrade>
        <ExpandedDataDimensionsReturned code="T" description="Enhanced Trade with All 6.0 Trade Fields" />
        <CreditorId>
          <CustomerNumber>801ON00630</CustomerNumber>
          <Name>BK OF AMER</Name>
          <Industry code="ON" description="National Credit Card Cos." />
        </CreditorId>
        <DateReported format="MM/CCYY">07/2019</DateReported>
        <DateOpened format="MM/CCYY">12/2007</DateOpened>
        <AccountNumber>4509128960678</AccountNumber>
        <HighCreditAmount>0020500</HighCreditAmount>
        <BalanceAmount>0000076</BalanceAmount>
        <PortfolioType code="R" description="Revolving or Option (open-end account)" />
        <Status code="1" description="Pays Acct As Agreed" />
        <MonthsReviewed>21</MonthsReviewed>
        <AccountDesignator code="I" description="Individual" />
        <DateOfLastActivity format="MM/CCYY">07/2019</DateOfLastActivity>
        <ScheduledPaymentAmount>0000015</ScheduledPaymentAmount>
        <UpdateIndicator code="*" description="Tape" />
        <Narratives>
          <Narrative code="FE" description="Credit Card" />
          <Narrative code="AZ" description="Amount In H/C Column Is Credit Limit" />
        </Narratives>
        <ExpandedCreditorId>
          <Name>BANK OF AMERICA</Name>
        </ExpandedCreditorId>
        <ExpandedDateReported format="MM/CCYY">07/2019</ExpandedDateReported>
        <ExpandedDateOpened format="MM/CCYY">12/2007</ExpandedDateOpened>
        <ExpandedCreditLimit>000020500</ExpandedCreditLimit>
        <ExpandedBalanceAmount>000000076</ExpandedBalanceAmount>
        <ExpandedPortfolioType code="R" description="Revolving or Option (open-end account)" />
        <ExpandedStatus code="1" description="Pays Acct As Agreed" />
        <ExpandedNarratives>
          <Narrative code="FE" description="Credit Card" />
        </ExpandedNarratives>
        <ExpandedScheduledPaymentAmount>000000015</ExpandedScheduledPaymentAmount>
      </USTrade>
      <USTrade>
        <ExpandedDataDimensionsReturned code="T" description="Enhanced Trade with All 6.0 Trade Fields" />
        <CreditorId>
          <CustomerNumber>801ON00630</CustomerNumber>
          <Name>BK OF AMER</Name>
          <Industry code="ON" description="National Credit Card Cos." />
        </CreditorId>
        <DateReported format="MM/CCYY">10/2018</DateReported>
        <DateOpened format="MM/CCYY">12/2007</DateOpened>
        <AccountNumber>4509128960565</AccountNumber>
        <Status code="B" description="Lost or Stolen Card" />
        <DateOfLastActivity format="MM/CCYY">10/2018</DateOfLastActivity>
        <UpdateIndicator code="*" description="Tape" />
        <Narratives>
          <Narrative code="FE" description="Credit Card" />
        </Narratives>
        <ExpandedCreditorId>
          <Name>BANK OF AMERICA</Name>
        </ExpandedCreditorId>
        <ExpandedDateReported format="MM/CCYY">10/2018</ExpandedDateReported>
        <ExpandedDateOpened format="MM/CCYY">12/2007</ExpandedDateOpened>
        <ExpandedStatus code="B" description="Lost or Stolen Card" />
        <ExpandedNarratives>
          <Narrative code="FE" description="Credit Card" />
        </ExpandedNarratives>
      </USTrade>
```

I keep getting "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element" error.

As I am digging thru the data, I am seeing some USTrades that do not have the elements I am searching for - Would that be causing the issue?  If so, how do I account for that? (IE A UsTrade does not have a ScheduledPaymentAmount element)

Thanks

Comment: Really depends on your wanted output - i assume your example is simplyfied ...
How about `xmlStr.Descendants("ScheduledPaymentAmount").where( //something )`. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838396/2590375). Maybe you need to give `Descendants` a list of wanted xml nodes.

Comment: What I am trying to do is sum the ScheduledPaymentAmount BUT only when the the balance is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query to only search for objects that have a `ScheduledPaymentAmount` element. For example

```
var trades = from x in xmlStr.Descendants("USTrade")
                    where (int) x.Element("BalanceAmount") > 0 
                    and x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount") != null
                    select  (int)x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount");
```

Comment: var trades = from x in xmlStr.Descendants("USTrade")
                    where x.Element("BalanceAmount") != null 
                          & x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount") != null 
                          & (int) x.Element("BalanceAmount") > 0
                    select (int) x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount");    Is what I made from your example.  It works without "& (int) x.Element("BalanceAmount") > 0" but as soon as I add that line I get the Value Null error.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to stem from the 0000 value.  I ended up creating a new class and added the BalanceAmount and ScheduledPaymentAmount as properties.  Then I did:

```
            var trades = (from x in xmlStr.Descendants("USTrade")
                         where x.Element("BalanceAmount") != null
                               & x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount") != null
                         select new USTrade
                         {
                             BalanceAmount = (int) x.Element("BalanceAmount") ,
                             ScheduledPaymentAmount = (int)x.Element("ScheduledPaymentAmount")
                         }).ToList();


            monthlySum = (from y in trades
                where y.BalanceAmount > 0
                select y.ScheduledPaymentAmount).Sum();
```

Presto, all good.  This works better in the long run as I will want to eventually pull more values.